# Prevent multiple click events and change target value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have UI with a list of users in a table. Each entry / user has two buttons. One of the buttons is a 'check' button.

```
<button type="submit" id="$id_from_db" class="bg-aqua btnCheckUser">Check</button>
```

When a check button is clicked for a particular user a `POST` request is sent to a server. While the request is loading all buttons should be disabled, the button which started the request should change its class from `bg-puple` to `bg-aqua`
and its text from `Check` to `Checking...`. If the request returns an error (which is indicated by `result` having the value `1`) the button should change its class from `bg-aqua` to `bg-danger`. If there is no error the class should change from `bg-aqua` to `bg-navy` and the text from `Checking...` to `User Okay`.

I'm able to achieve this but it does not only affect the button which started the request but all buttons.

This is my code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnCheckUser", function() {
      var Item_Number = $(this).attr("Item_Number");
      /************************** MANIPULATE BUTTONS *******************************************************************************/
      $(this).removeClass('bg-purple').addClass('bg-aqua');
      $(this).html('Checking ...');
      $(this).attr("disabled", true);
      $('.btnViewUser').attr("disabled", true);
      /******************************* PROCESS AJAX **************************************************************************/
      var value = {
        Item_Number: Item_Number
      };
      $.ajax({
            url: "./plugins/serverside/CheckUserStatus",
            type: "POST",
            data: value,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (data.result == 1) {
                  $(this).removeClass('bg-aqua').addClass('bg-danger');
                  $("#CheckUser").html('Failed!');
                  $('.btnCheckUser').attr("disabled", false);
                  $('.btnViewUser').attr("disabled", false);
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    var table = $('#User_Table').DataTable();
                    table.ajax.reload(null, false);
                  }, 3500);
                } else if (data.result == 2) {
                  //------------------------ IF User Okay -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                 
                  $("#CheckUser").removeClass('bg-aqua').addClass('bg-navy');
                  $("#CheckUser").html('User Okay');
                  $('.btnCheckUser').attr("disabled", false);
                  $('.btnViewUser').attr("disabled", false);
                }
```

How can I fix this and only affect the button which started the request, but still disable all buttons when a request is loading?

Comment: So assign data attributes of the user id's to the buttons and then use that information to manipulate the correct button(s)?

Comment: You would need to assign user ID's to the buttons like @gforce301 suggested, or rather than doing $('.btnViewUser').attr("disabled", true); you would need to do something like $(this).parent().find('.btnViewUser').attr("disabled", true); to specify which button you're targeting based on the context. (I can't tell whether that will work or not, or what exactly the targeting sequence would be since I can't see your html)

Comment: You mixed up some classes there.. you're talking about `bg-danger` but your code says `btn-danger`. I edited it to be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2ka0mgo/33/)**

I stripped the code down to the parts which matter for the button logic. I'm using a dummy API and I randomly generate the result value as I have no access to the actual API you're using.

```
$(() => $('.btnCheckUser').on('click', ({ target }) => clickHandler(target)));

function clickHandler(button) {
  // Disable all buttons when one of them is clicked
  $('.btnCheckUser').prop('disabled', true);
  $('.btnViewUser').prop('disabled', true);

  // Remove all non standard classes, then add 'loading' class and text
  $(button).removeClass('bg-purple').removeClass('bg-navy').removeClass('bg-danger').addClass('bg-aqua');
  $(button).text('Loading...')

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=3',
    success: raw => {
      // Random result value
      const result = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 2;

      if (result === 1) {
        // Something went wrong, add 'danger' class and text
        $(button).addClass('bg-danger');
        $(button).text('Failed!')
      } else if (result === 2) {
        // Everything went fine, add 'success' class and text
        $(button).addClass('bg-navy');
        $(button).text('Success!');
      }
    },
    error: () => {
      // Add 'danger' class if something goes wrong
      $(button).addClass('btn-danger');
    },
    complete: () => {
      // Enable all buttons as we got a response
      $('.btnCheckUser').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.btnViewUser').prop('disabled', false);

      // Remove 'loading' class as we got a response
      $(button).removeClass('bg-aqua');
    }
  });
}
```

This should give you the expected behavior.

Comment: Your solution looks good on Fiddle. I was away from pc for some time. I guess this will solve my problem with the result it gave on the JSFiddle. Let me apply this to my API and I will write back with the results. Thanks to everyone who has contributed.

Comment: I have accepted @rodrigo's answer as the right one. When I applied it to my project, the check user button doesn't click. But I have to accept the answer cos on the JSFiddle he posted, it worked fine and that is the expected behavior that I want to achieve. As for my project, I don't know why the button doesn't click anymore when I added this answer to it and there are no errors in the developer console to at least, point me in the possible area where there are errors. The Check button simply stopped clicking.

Answer (score -1):

hello there this is truly easy what you have to do is

```
function TheClickerFunction(){
    $("body").on("click",".YourButton",function(){
    //this will only affect the clicked element 
    $(this).attr("disabled",true);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
TheClickerFunction();
});
/*
i think creating a global counter and increment it on each element would b better*/
var GlobalCounter=  0;
function DynamicBuilder(){
var stringBuilder="";
for(var i = 0; i< lengthOfYourElement ; i++){
GlobalCounter+=1;
stringBuilder+="<input type='submit' id='myButton"+GlobalCounter+"'></input>";
}
$("body").append(stringBuidler);
}
in this way each time a click is made 
$(".yourClass").click(function(){
var elementID = $(this).attr("id");
//here you can do what ever you want with its id
})
*/
```